# datatable: Javascript sourced data not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to be able to create a table from dynamic information passed directly to DataTables, rather than having it read from the document using DataTables (a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library)

I have this table

```
var dataSet = [
                  ['IOS-LSLSLS','PRODUCT-NAME','CATEGORY','MANUFACTURER','COUNTRY','RETAILER1, RETAILER2'],
                  ['ANDROID-LSLSLS','PRODUCT-NAME2','CATEGORY2','MANUFACTURER2','COUNTRY2','RETAILER31, RETAILER32']];


oTable = $('#devicesDatatableId').dataTable( {
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "bStateSave": true,
                    "data":  dataSet,        
                    "sScrollY": "auto",
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                                    { "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [ "asc" ], "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                                    { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                                    { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                                    { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
                                    { "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
                                    { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 5 ] }
                                ],
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bSortCellsTop": true,
                    "sDom": 'tlpi<"clear">',

                });
```

and

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display normaltable" id="devicesDatatableId">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>                            
                                        <th >Model</th>
                                        <th >Product name</th>
                                        <th >Category:</th>                                         
                                        <th >Manufacturer:</th>
                                        <th >Country(ies):</th>
                                        <th >Retailer(s):</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="thefilters">                         
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>                                          
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>
                                        <td ><input name="" size="" maxlength="" id="" value="" type="text"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Model</th>
                                        <th>Product name</th>
                                        <th>Category:</th>
                                        <th>Manufacturer:</th>
                                        <th>Country(ies):</th>
                                        <th>Retailer(s):</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody/>    
                            </table>
```

But no data appears in the table

Comment: use Server side option with ajax in datatable and dynamically get data from database

Comment: You're missing an end quote after `RETAILER31` on the third line

Comment: no, the full text is "RETAILER31, RETAILER32"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quote from the end:

```
var dataSet = [['IOS-LSLSLS','PRODUCT-NAME','CATEGORY','MANUFACTURER','COUNTRY','RETAILER1, RETAILER2'],
             ['ANDROID-LSLSLS','PRODUCT-NAME2','CATEGORY2','MANUFACTURER2','COUNTRY2','RETAILER31, RETAILER32']];
```

Here is a working version: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/7sd0e3c0/1/)

Comment: unfortunately same result

Comment: Well you're clearly doing some else wrong as I have PROVED that it works in the jsfiddle.